# regexp get what is left after the match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, timezone

So I have a select element with options of different timezones, see the exampel below.

`<option value="2.0">(GMT +2:00) Kaliningrad, South Africa</option>`

I want to replace everything after `(GMT +2:00)` to "Local time".
I came up with this regexp below but it only matches `(GMT +2:00)`, I want to target and change the rest of the string. And maybe I should also be using replace() insted.

```
var matches = $(this).html().match(/\(GMT [+-][0-9]+:00\)/);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var finalString = $(this).html().replace(/(\(GMT [+-][0-9]+:00\))(.*)/, "$1 Local Time");
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/r65Hp/

Comment: The OP is using `.html()`, which also retrieves the HTML tag. Using this will get rid of the closing `</option>` tag.

Comment: I changed `.html()` to `.text()` so there is no problems for me with this one, thanks @Cybernate

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select.whatever option').text(function(i, text) {   
  return text.replace(/\).*?$/, ') Local Time');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkySF/).

Comment: @Null What specifically is wrong with it? Does the fiddle not return the correct string?

Comment: @Null You could assume `this` were the `option` elements in my sample.